# Why does my training loss decrease with number of samples?

Tags: neural-networks, conv-neural-network, training-error

I'm training a convolutional U-Net-like structure for image restoration, with SSIM loss and ADAM.
I have ~1500 training samples and ~350 validation samples partitioned at random.  My batches have just one image each.

Now I'm plotting the learning curve (losses after 10 epochs of training with varying sized data subsets,) and am surprised to find the training loss decreasing as the number of samples increases. (The validation set is unchanged here.)  The model is re-initialised after each round.  For training loss I'm taking the mean loss over all the batches in the epoch.

Can anyone explain why the training loss is decreasing?  I'm flummoxed.

[image: Learning curve after 10 epochs.]

In case it is relevant, my training loss and validation loss are very close (low variance), but I have high bias.  Here's some typical loss data using the full 1500 data set:

[image: Loss versus epoch for training and validation.]

Comment: Is the number of *updates* the same or different across models? The learning rate?

Comment: There's one update for each data sample, so more data -> more updates.  Learning rate is constant 1e-3.

Comment: It doesn't seem surprising to me that more updates gives a model with a lower training loss.

Comment: It's more updates, but it also has to match more samples.  Every learning curve I've seen goes up for training data.  However, you have a point.  Possibly I should run the small datasets for longer, in case they hadn't converged.